# How to filter a html table to match cases and words exactly using simple javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I found a solution to filter the table on the [How to filter a html table using simple javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51187477/how-to-filter-a-html-table-using-simple-javascript)
But my usecase is to filter it to match cases and word. 
For example if table contains John and Johnaton, if i search Jon, it shouldn't return anything and if i search John, it should only return John.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:60%;">Name</th>
    <th style="width:40%;">Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Johnaton snabbkop</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Johnny Trading</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Johnea Essen</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jon Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jonny Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>North/South</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Paris specialites</td>
    <td>France</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are

Note I gave the table a thead/tbody and moved the ID

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("myInput").addEventListener("input", function() {
    const val = this.value.trim().toUpperCase();
    const filter = new RegExp('\\b' + val + '\\b'); // word boundary regex
    const trs = document.querySelectorAll("#myTable tr");
    for (let i = 0; i < trs.length; i++) {
      trs[i].style.display = val ? "none" : "";
      const tds = trs[i].querySelectorAll("td");
      found = false;
      for (let j = 0; j < tds.length; j++) {
        const text = tds[j].textContent.toUpperCase();
        if (filter.test(text)) found = true;
      }
      if (found) trs[i].style.display = "";
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name" />

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr class="header">
      <th style="width:60%;">Name</th>
      <th style="width:40%;">Country</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <td>John Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Johnaton snabbkop</td>
      <td>Sweden</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Johnny Trading</td>
      <td>UK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Johnea Essen</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jon Bacchus Winecellars</td>
      <td>Canada</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jonny Alimentari Riuniti</td>
      <td>Italy</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>North/South</td>
      <td>UK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Paris specialites</td>
      <td>France</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

For only names:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("myInput").addEventListener("input", function() {
    const val = this.value.trim().toUpperCase();
    const filter = new RegExp('\\b' + val + '\\b'); // word boundary regex
    const trs = document.querySelectorAll("#myTable tr");
    for (let i = 0; i < trs.length; i++) {
      const text = trs[i].querySelector("td").textContent.toUpperCase(); // or td:first-child
      trs[i].style.display = filter.test(text) ? "" : "none"
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name" />

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr class="header">
      <th style="width:60%;">Name</th>
      <th style="width:40%;">Country</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <td>John Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Johnaton snabbkop</td>
      <td>Sweden</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Johnny Trading</td>
      <td>UK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Johnea Essen</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jon Bacchus Winecellars</td>
      <td>Canada</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jonny Alimentari Riuniti</td>
      <td>Italy</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>North/South</td>
      <td>UK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Paris specialites</td>
      <td>France</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: So this solve my problem, but this what if i only have to search from name only. In this solution if you search by any country name, it will shows all the entries.

Comment: That is because we look in all cells. We can restrict to only names

Comment: If you only need one cell's content, then see the update. It is much simpler

Answer (score 0):

In example you've find function indexOf search for sub-string, to find exact match taking into account that === won't work for data contract like (Name Surname) remove toUpperCase() and split string by whitecase. So change condition to:

```
if (td.innerHTML.split(' ').indexOf(filter) >-1)
```

Also in yor data I see values like `North/South` so you need additional splits by all separator characters. Or use regex to indicate all separators.